# Sure post in Magento's built in UPS Integration

Tags: shipping, ups

Last Year our company decided to offer UPS Surepost as a discreet shipping option before UPS got around to adding it as an option in their Rating API.

To work around this, and still give customers accurate shipping rates i ended up having to use WebShopApps MatrixRates extension to build a massive cumbersome csv file mapping destination zip code (generalized to the first 3 or 2 digits) to price.

This is not an ideal long term solution.  To keep it up to date with UPS's rate and fuel surcharge changes requires a good deal of work every few months.

It looks like UPS has finally added surepost into their api.

Is Enterprise 1.13 able to display surepost rates without any additional custom development?

Comment: UPS does support SurePost via their API's since the beginning of the year. Has Magento taken advantage of this yet? Does Magento support SurePost shipping and rating?

Answer (score 1):

You should have got the UPS Zones extension, this allows you to enter zones rather than use zipcodes and has been used on many sites to implement SurePost. You can do in just a few lines.

EE1.13 doesnt implement SurePost, and I've not seen it mentioned in any UPS API.

Comment: Getting information out of UPS is like pulling hens teeth. You can get a few minor details, but good luck on extracting a really well kept secret. Basically, it is commercial ground rate without any extra fuel and rural rates. It's uninsured unless you do a beatdown on your local Rep, at which point they will do a deal for a flat insurance of $0.75 per $100 and up to $5000. NBL on Magento implementing it soon. I put together a module to do SurePost on 1.4.2.0, but we've discontinued using as we get far better service through Endicia and the USPS for this delivery level. Endicia insurance works

Comment: Looking into WSA's zone rates as we're a two location shop. It's probably the better investment.